# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable when i create "legend"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.scatter(df.age[df.target==1],
           df.thalach[df.target==1],
           color="salmon")

plt.scatter(df.age[df.target==0],
           df.thalach[df.target==0],
           color="lightblue")

plt.xlabel="age"
plt.ylabel="max"
plt.legend(["disease","No disease"]);
```

this is my code and I get this error:

```
---> 12 plt.legend(["disease","No disease"])

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

and if I assign the `plt.xlabel=("age")`

I get the same error about str.

I know that I get this error because I already assigned plt.ylabel ,and plt legend in code above, but can't I have multiple plots in the same jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 2):

> I already assigned plt.ylabel ,and plt legend in code above

`plt.ylabel` and `plt.legend` are *functions*: you call them with the appropriate arguments to set the labels, legends etc. You shouldn't assign things to them because now `plt.legend` is a list and can't be used properly. Restart the notebook and consult [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) for examples of how to use Matplotlib. The gist is, almost nothing in `plt` is supposed to be assigned to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `label` parameter in the `scatter` method and then call `legend` method without any args.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.scatter(df.age[df.target==1],
           df.thalach[df.target==1],
           color="salmon",
           label="Disease",
)

plt.scatter(df.age[df.target==0],
           df.thalach[df.target==0],
           color="lightblue",
           label="No disease",
)

plt.xlabel("age")
plt.ylabel("max")
plt.legend()
plt.plot()
```